# Replace main input with button in react-select

Tags: react-select

I use [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) for a multi selection dropdown. By default, react-select displays labels inside an input. I would like to replace this input with a simple button (without any labels or anything fancy...just a simple button). The button would popup the dropdown.

I can't find how to modify the input.

Here is my default select:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Select options={options} isMulti />
)
```